# How can I separate Visual State Managment from Custom Control template?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

How can I separate Visual State Management from a Custom Control template?

I have one Custom Control, but with several different faces placed in templates.
All templates must have same state-based visualisation.
Is there any way to set my VSM once only? Otherwise I need to copy the VSM code in each template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-templating often leads to duplicate code, especially for VSM code. There isn't an easy way to abstract out that code today, unfortunately.